# Upload file to a graphql springboot microservice from another springboot microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, graphql

I have one springboot microservice which is implemented using graphql technology and exposes a **mutation** as endpoint to upload file and other file related information.

```
mutation($file: Upload, $fileInfo: FileInfo) {
    uploadFile(file: $file, fileInfo: $fileInfo)
}

input FileInfo {
    name: String
    size: Int
}
```

Curl command to call this,

```
curl -v -L http://localhost:8087/graphql \
-F operations='{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload, $fileInfo: FileInfo) { uploadFile(file: $file, fileInfo: $fileInfo)}", "variables": { "file": null, "fileInfo": {"name": "test.json", "size": 500} } }' \
-F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"]}' \
-F 0=test.json
```

Same achieved through postman,

[image]

I know Its easy to call this mutation endpoint and upload file from UI as there are many good clients available for UI but I have to call this mutation from another springboot microservice which has file as **InputStream** and FileInfo stored in a **HashMap<String, Object>**.

How can I achieve this from java code? can we create a **restTemplate.exchange** or **restTemplate.postForEntity** http request with **MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA** as content type to achieve this? a code snippet would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

It gave me a hard time also, so here you go.
[Spring Boot 2.6.3 / DGS Netflix / Java 17]

I added the Query in a 'uploadFile.graphql' file

1. uploadFile.graphql

```
mutation($file: Upload!, $fileInfo: FileInfo!) {
    uploadFile(file: $file, fileInfo: $fileInfo)
}
```

2. Here is a sample Code. (didn't run it but should work)

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private void uploadFile(){

  // Build the Query Variables Map
  var fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.json", 500);
  var fileInfoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fileInfo);

  var variables = new LinkedHashMap();
  variables.put("fileInfo", fileInfoJson);
  variables.put("file", null);

  // Build the GraphQL-Params
  var query = StreamUtils.copyToString( new ClassPathResource("uploadFile.graphql").getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());

  var params = new LinkedHashMap();
  params.put("operationName", "FileUploadMutation");
  params.put("variables", variables);
  params.put("query", query)

  // Build Multi-Part Upload Request
  var file = Paths.get("src/test/resources/test.json");
  try{
    var contentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file)
    var multiPartFile = new MultiPartByteArrayResource(file.getFileName(), contentBytes);

    var formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.set("operations", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(params));
    formData.set("map": "{\"file\": [\"variables.file\"]}");
    formData.set("file",multiPartFile);

    var headers = new HttpHeaders(); // If you need additional headers... here you go!
  
    var requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(formData, headers);
    var response = restTemplate.exchange("/graphql", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    //Done!
  } catch(final IOException e){
    log.error(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I use it for Integration Testing  of my GraphQl-Upload Mutations.