# How to Upload files with Spring GraphQlClient?

Tags: spring-graphql

I'm looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#client-graphqlclient), but it does not mention file Upload.

The GraphQl Upload service I need to consume is [this one](https://developer.funcionalmais.com/api-ref/index.html#operation-prescription_addprescription-Mutations).

Would it be possible with `GraphQlClient`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible indeed.

You should build your `GraphQlClient` or reuse a previous one. Then, you should write the the `document` (or refer to an existing one using `documentName`) specifying the variables required. Finally, you assign that variable to a value, which can be any `Object` (in your case, a file; in my example, an `Integer` number 1), using the `variable` method of the `RequestSpec`.

```
graphQlClient
                .mutate()
                .header("Authorization","Basic XXXXX")
                .build()
                .document("""
                            query artistaPorId($unId:ID){
                                artistaPorId(id:$unId){
                                    apellido
                                }
                             }
                        """)
                .variable("unId",1)
                .retrieve("artistaPorId")
                .toEntity(Artista.class)
                .subscribe( // handle onNext, onError, etc
                );
```

My `schema.graphqls`:

```
type Query {
    artistaPorId(id:ID): Artista
}

type Artista {
    id: ID
    apellido: String
    estilo: String
}
```

Comment: The upload endpoint I need to use uses multipart form data, I just discovered while trying your sample.

Comment: We should ask Rossen or one of the guys from the team, since I'm not sure if that is supported at this point

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out with the help of [this answner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314559/upload-file-to-a-graphql-springboot-microservice-from-another-springboot-microse).

This uses Spring WebClient. I just need to figure it out how to extract data from the response (it's a graphql response).

```
var variables = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
variables.put("cartao", cartao);
variables.put("mime", MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
variables.put("file", null);

var query = StreamUtils.copyToString(new ClassPathResource("/graphql-documents/UploadPrescriptionMutation.graphql").getInputStream(),
                                     Charset.defaultCharset());

var params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("operationName", "upload");
params.put("query", query);
params.put("variables", variables);

MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.part("operations", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(params));
builder.part("map", "{\"uploaded_file\": [\"variables.file\"]}");
builder.part("uploaded_file", new FileSystemResource(file));

return webClient.post()
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token))
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Prescription_AddPrescriptionDto.class)
                .block();
```

GraphQL file:

```
mutation upload($file: Prescription_Upload!, $cartao: String!, $mime: String!) {
    Prescription_uploadPrescription(
        file: $file uploadInfo: {
            cardNumber: $cartao
            source: UNKNOWN
            mime: $mime })
    {
        id
        uploadedAt
        deletedAt
        expiresAt
        source
        file
        name
        cardNumber
        identity
        status
        storage
        originalName
        extension
    }
}
```